# A Variation of the even-town odd-town problem

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

> Let assume facebook has $n$ users. Mark Zuckerberg decided that people are allowed to open groups under the following restrictions:
>
> 1) No two different groups can exactly the same participants.
>
> 2) The number of users in each group is even.
>
> 3) Every two group has an odd number of common users.
>
> Denote by $m$ the maximal number of groups that can be formed in facebook under the restrictions mentioned above. Prove $m \leq n$.

I tried solving this by defined a matrix, multiplying it by its transpose and using some rank considerations I thought I could derive the bound, but I didn't succeed. Could you please give me a hint?

The question had anther subsection : prove that in the case that $n$ is even than we have stron inequality

Comment: What stops you from pairing the users and forming $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ groups?

Comment: @dtldarek I mixed up, I will fix the question

Comment: @dtldarek now it is supposed to be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be the set of users, and let $\mathscr{G}\subseteq\wp([n])$ be the collection of groups. As **leonbloy** pointed out, we can use the classic problem to show that $|\mathscr{G}|\le n+1$. Suppose that $|\mathscr{G}|=n+1$. For each $G\in\mathscr{G}$ let $v_G$ be the vector associated with $G$; $v_G\cdot v_H=1$ for distinct $G,H\in\mathscr{G}$, while $v_G\cdot v_G=0$ for all $G\in\mathscr{G}$. (All arithmetic is done modulo $2$.) The $n+1$ vectors $v_G$ for $G\in\mathscr{G}$ must be linearly dependent, so there are scalars $c_G$ for $G\in\mathscr{G}$, not all $0$, such that $\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}c_Gv_G=0$. Then for each $H\in\mathscr{G}$ we have

$$0=v_H\cdot\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}c_Gv_G=\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}\setminus\{H\}}c_G\;.$$

Let $H$ and $K$ be distinct members of $\mathscr{G}$; then

$$c_H-c_K=\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}\setminus\{K\}}c_G-\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}\setminus\{H\}}c_G=0\;,$$

so $c_H=c_K$, and we must have $c_G=1$ for all $G\in\mathscr{G}$.

Fix $H\in\mathscr{G}$; $\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}\setminus\{H\}}1=0$, so $n$ is even. For each $G\in\mathscr{G}$ let $G\,'=[n]\setminus G$; $n$ and $|G|$ are even, so $|G'|$ is even. Moreover, if $G$ and $H$ are distinct members of $\mathscr{G}$, then

$$|G\,'\cap H'|=n-|G\cup H|=n-|G|-|H|+|G\cap H|$$

is odd. Let $\mathscr{G}'=\{G\,':G\in\mathscr{G}\}$; then $\mathscr{G}'$ satisfies the same conditions as $\mathscr{G}$, soby the same argument we must have $\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}v_{G\,'}=0$, where $v_{G\,'}$ is of course the vector corresponding to the set $G\,'$. But then

$$0=\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}v_G+\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}v_{G\,'}=\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}(v_G+v_{G\,'})=\sum_{G\in\mathscr{G}}\mathbf{1}\;,$$

where $\mathbf{1}=v_{[n]}$ is the vector of all ones, and it follows that $n+1=|\mathscr{G}|$ is even and hence that $n$ is odd. This is a contradiction, and it follows that $|\mathscr{G}|$ cannot be $n+1$: it must be at most $n$.

Comment: Simething look fishy, since in the second subsections we need to prove that f $n$ is even , then $m \leq n-1$

Comment: @UserB95: I'm afraid that I've no idea what you're talking about. The argument simply assumes that $m=n+1$ and derives a contradiction.

Comment: The question had two subsections:
1) Prove $m \leq n$......

2) Assuming $n$ is even prove that $m<n$......

That what I meant

Comment: Do you have a clue now?

Comment: @UserB95: I’ve thought about it a bit; no success so far, but I’ve not given up yet.

Comment: @UserB95: Another user [just asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177740/proving-the-parity-of-subsets/1179011#1179011) about the same thing, and I was finally able to supply a proof; take a look at my answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the $m\times n$ matrix whose rows correspond to groups, whose columns correspond to people, with a $1$ in an entry if that person is in that group, and $0$ otherwise. From now on, we will think of these entries as elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. The conditions on even sizes/odd intersections then imply
$$
AA^T\equiv J_m-I_m,
$$
where $J_m$ is the $m\times m$ matrix filled with ones, and $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix. Therefore,
$$
\def\r{\text{rank }}\r A\ge \r AA^T=\r (J_m-I_m).
$$
Furthermore, the matrix $A$ has a nontrivial kernel; letting $v$ be the $n\times 1$ column vector with all ones, then $Av\equiv{\bf 0}\pmod 2$, since each row has an even number of ones. This means $\r A\le n-1$, so that
$$
\r (J_m-I_m)\le n-1 \tag{*}
$$
Now, we need the following:

> **Lemma**: $$\r (J_m-I_m)=\begin{cases}m &  m \text{ is even}\\ m-1 & m \text{ is odd}.\end{cases}$$

*Proof*: When $m$ is even, we have $(J_m-I_m)^2\equiv (J_m)^2+(I_m)^2\equiv 0+I_m$, so that $J_m-I_m$ is invertible. When $m$ is odd, then $(J_m-I_m)w=0$, where $w$ is the $m\times 1$ vector of all ones. This proves $\r(J_m-I_m)\le m-1$; since the upper $(m-1)\times (m-1)$ submatrix is $J_{m-1}-I_{m-1}$, which was just shown to be invertible, the rank is indeed $m-1$. $\square$

In either case, we have $m-1\le \r(J_m-I_m)$, which combined with $(*)$ implies $m\le n$. This answers your first question. Furthermore, when $n$ is even, we cannot have $m=n$, otherwise we would have $\r(J_m-I_m)=\r(J_n-I_n)=n\not \le n-1$, contradicting $(*)$. Therefore, when $n$ is even, we can further conclude $m\le n-1$.

Comment: Thanks! I should have done this with coefficient field ${\mathbb F}_2={\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$, but instead, when $n$ is even I worked on the reals and stuck in linear algebra - how stupid I have been!

Answer (score 0):

Lets call this (groups are even, intersection are odd) a  "$(n,m)$ even/odd town".

By adding a dummy user to each group, we now have the classical "$(n+1,m)$ odd/even town" (groups are odd, intersection are even)

Then we get that $m\le n+1$

(Yes, this is slightly weaker than your inequality I'm noy sure if this can be improved - are you sure you got it right?)

Comment: It’s right, but the argument is a bit indirect; see my answer. (I had the advantage of having seen this proof before.)